# Responsive image and media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm kind of sure this is not possible but I ask because it seems unbelievable.

I have some  elements styled for reponsive design

```
img {max-width:100%;height:auto;}
```

but the images have to be different depending on the device (I won't load heavy wide screen images on a phone device).

Since media queries aren't supported inline, I could go for a css background solution, but background-size is not perfectly supported and honnestly it would look more like a hack.

Can anyone confirm that "widely supported device related responsive images" are not properly possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Well a great prayer confirmed it :
http://css-tricks.com/on-responsive-images/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to deliver a different image depending on the viewpoint.

[Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) could be the solution you are looking for. Easy enough to setup and confirm.

A second possiblity which might give you even more control is [Adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs) . I've used it with good success on several sites. You load a small javascript file in the head of your document. This tests viewpoint width and then dependending on the results, it will send the appropriate CSS file. It has wider browser support than @media requests.

If you could live with using background images, then it would work well, and since you could specify different images for different viewpoints, you aren't up the creek with browsers that don't understand background image sizes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adaptive image seems not to work (full size image is always loaded whatever the screen width) but Adapt.js seems like a honorable solution. Mark it as accepted answer as this seems hard to get any better.

Comment: I'm pleased you found something that works well for you. I've found that responsive design often throws unexpected challenges!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Responsive Img jQuery plugin](http://responsiveimg.com).

It's made to automatically create and swap in different-sized images at different breakpoints, based on the container's width.

If you already have different versions on your image created and on your server, the plugin will just swap those in at the right breakpoint sizes.

Therefore, you can create new images for all the different breakpoint sizes you want, and the plugin takes care of the rest.

It's not CSS, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

**2014 update**

There is a nice and new technique here : 
http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_images_experimenting_with_context_aware_image_sizing/

It requires a small js, a 1x1px blank image, a few extra markup for img tags, and some .htaccess rules.

Seems to work fine so far.